# Laravel - Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached in localhost:8000

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm using PhpStorm and `localhost:8000`.

I'm trying to login but after submit my information this error was appeared:

> **Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting**

I read about this issue and figure out that changing *php.ini* and comment this line:

***zend_extension = "d:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.8/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.1.2-5.3-vc9.dll***

my be helpful.
But I don't know where is `php.ini` on `localhost:8000` . Any suggestion?

Comment: It's propably becouse you've got some function that calls itself. Could you show some code?

Comment: We're developing on team and other members can login nicely.

Comment: @AdamPietrasiak isn't it problem in my files?

Comment: Search for it in your drive, php.ini is under"d:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.8/

Comment: Outputting the result of [`php_ini_loaded_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-ini-loaded-file.php) will print the full path to the `php.ini` file.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ Solved.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get this error, is because Laravel calls functions in a nested level too deeply. For example, the following does three nested levels (main body, function a, function b).

```
<?php
function b()
{
}

function a()
{
    b();
}

a();
?>
```

The debugger extension Xdebug, makes sure that this nesting does not go on infinitely, as this (used to) makes the server crash. Try this **on the command line**: `php -r 'function a() { a(); } a();'` and you'll likely get an out of memory error.

By default, Xdebug sets a maximum of these levels to "100", although more recent versions change the default to "256". You can change the value in php.ini with:

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level=1000
```